# Change SQL statement to EXISTS clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, query-performance, exists

Given the following SQL statenent:

```
select 
    OBJECT_ID
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1703 A 
WHERE A.STAMP_ID >1 
    AND A.OBJECT_REV NOT IN (
select MAX(OBJECT_REV)
from HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
where B.COMMITID <= 6066 
    and B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID 
    )
```

In this query the where clause `AND OBJECT_REV NOT IN` must be changeed from `NOT IN` to an equivalent `EXISTS` statement.

We try this

```
select 
OBJECT_ID
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1703 A 
WHERE A.STAMP_ID >1 
AND exists (
select * 
from HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
where B.COMMITID <= 6066 
and B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID 
and B.OBJECT_REV > A.OBJECT_REV) ;
```

It gives us close results, but not same

Comment: Please show what you have tried: trial and error is a better way of learning than simply asking someone to do the work for you.

Comment: Qualify the column names with the table alias they belong to.

Comment: The equivalent of a `NOT IN` would be `NOT EXISTS` rewriting it to use `EXISTS` would be a completely different query

Comment: Not an answer to your question but `A.OBJECT_REV NOT IN (SELECT MAX(...` seems weird since the latter returns a single record.  You might consider `A.OBJECT_REV <> (SELECT MAX(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT A.OBJECT_ID
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1703 A 
WHERE 
  A.STAMP_ID > 1 
  AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (
      SELECT MAX(B.OBJECT_REV) MAXOBJECT_REV
      FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
      WHERE B.COMMITID <= 6066 AND B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID 
    ) t
    WHERE t.MAXOBJECT_REV = A.OBJECT_REV
  )
```

Note: the subquery of NOT IN:

```
select MAX(OBJECT_REV)
from HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
where B.COMMITID <= 6066 and B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
```

returns only 1 row with 1 column.
So instead of `NOT IN` you could use `<>` like this:

```
SELECT A.OBJECT_ID
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1703 A 
WHERE 
  A.STAMP_ID > 1 
  AND 
  A.OBJECT_REV <> (
    SELECT MAX(OBJECT_REV)
    FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
    WHERE B.COMMITID <= 6066 AND B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID 
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, 
But We got error on DB2:
"A.OBJECT_ID" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56

Looks like error for B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID

Comment: B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID is a part of your code. Does your 1st query work?

Comment: yes, first query works. Your query works on Microsoft SQL but doesn't work on DB2. Original query works on boths server

Comment: The query is fine syntactically in DB2 also, check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e7b21399e1d88933a05da49baf12adc0

Comment: yes, your query pass db2 check syntax but it fails when we try to run:
SELECT A.OBJECT_ID
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1703 A 
WHERE 
  A.STAMP_ID > 1 
  AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (
      SELECT MAX(B.OBJECT_REV) MAXOBJECT_REV
      FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_1709763 B 
      WHERE B.COMMITID <= 6066 AND B.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID 
    ) t
    WHERE t.MAXOBJECT_REV = A.OBJECT_REV
  )

"A.OBJECT_ID" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56

Script: Script5.sql
Database Name: TCB17_3

Comment: What is  `) "A.OBJECT_ID"` at the end? This is not part of my code. Of course it is syntactically wrong the way you use it.

Comment: this error message from DB2:
"A.OBJECT_ID" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56

Comment: This error is the result of your code which I don't know what it is because I don't know how you use my code. The code in my query is syntactically correct.